# Rails: How to use one form file_field to upload multiple selected files at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make an image heavy web app that allows you to upload multiple images. However, I don't want to pollute my site with a bunch of `file_field`s because it looks ugly and is also inconvenient, since the user has to upload multiple pics one by one like that. Is there a way to make it so that when you click the file_field box that you can select/highlight multiple files at once and upload them all at once? If so, how would I target each uploaded image so that I can display each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. `field_field` just elaborates into `input` tags of type `file` which, by specification, can only load a single file at a time.

You can, though, have a look at other solutions which can be fit into a Rails application such as [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) or [Plupload](http://planetrails.com/plupload-with-rails-3/)